# Flutter a lot of compilation errors after minor pubspec dependencies updated

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, pubspec

I'm working with VSC and Flutter, after one compilation I receive a lot of errors. Do not change anything, moreover when I rollback my code to another, stable branches, errors are the same. Android compilation return similar error. Currently I'm working on `Flutter 2.10.3` and do not change Flutter SDK version for a lot of weeks.
I cannot run program, there is none error in VSC Problems, but code still cannot pass compilation.

```
    2022-07-12 05:14:35.999 xcodebuild[6459:41574]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-20038/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-000D31690282001E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7ff1744e89d0>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600002a26200>{number = 9, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/92/kp551sh11bxbw0k5w4hl7dyc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IpM7GP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirbBMU5d/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1376:30: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '`'.
    Try inserting an identifier before '`'.
                    ErrorSummary(`'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.'),
                                 ^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1376:31: Error: Expected ',' before this.
                    ErrorSummary(`'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.'),
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1376:29: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                    ErrorSummary(`'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`.'),
                                ^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/assertions.dart:303:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      ErrorSummary(String message) : super(message, level: DiagnosticLevel.summary);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.3.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_date_time_picker.dart:355:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
          anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:133:19: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
    Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker({
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.3.1/lib/src/fields/form_builder_date_time_picker.dart:373:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
          anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:2413:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
    Future<TimeOfDay?> showTimePicker({
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/qqqqqqqq/qqqqqqqq2/qqqqqqqq3.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/92/kp551sh11bxbw0k5w4hl7dyc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.IpM7GP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirbBMU5d/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone (TUL IA iph12 pro).
Exited (sigterm)
```

Now I see, that I have a lot of small changes in `pubspec.lock`, but I do not add or edit any dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`, below diff from `Github Desktop`

```
  name: archive
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.2.2"
    version: "3.3.0"
  args:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: args
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.3.0"
    version: "2.3.1"
  async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -63,21 +63,21 @@ packages:
      name: crypto
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.0.1"
    version: "3.0.2"
  csslib:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: csslib
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.17.1"
    version: "0.17.2"
  cupertino_icons:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: cupertino_icons
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.0.4"
    version: "1.0.5"
  fake_async:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ packages:
      name: ffi
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.2"
    version: "1.2.1"
  file:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -110,7 +110,7 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_form_builder
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.1.1"
    version: "7.3.1"
  flutter_js:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -136,14 +136,14 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_native_splash
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.1"
    version: "2.1.6"
  flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.6"
  flutter_secure_storage:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -202,28 +202,28 @@ packages:
      name: flutter_widget_from_html_core
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.8.5+1"
    version: "0.8.5+3"
  form_builder_validators:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: form_builder_validators
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.6.1"
    version: "7.9.0"
  fwfh_text_style:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: fwfh_text_style
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.7.3+1"
    version: "2.7.3+2"
  get:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: get
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.6.1"
    version: "4.6.5"
  get_storage:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
@ -251,7 +251,7 @@ packages:
      name: http_parser
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.0.0"
    version: "4.0.1"
  image:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -294,6 +294,13 @@ packages:
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.3.1"
  lint:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: lint
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.8.2"
  lints:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -391,49 +398,49 @@ packages:
      name: path_provider
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.9"
    version: "2.0.11"
  path_provider_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_android
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.12"
    version: "2.0.14"
  path_provider_ios:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_ios
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.8"
    version: "2.0.9"
  path_provider_linux:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_linux
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.5"
    version: "2.1.7"
  path_provider_macos:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_macos
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.6"
  path_provider_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.3"
    version: "2.0.4"
  path_provider_windows:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: path_provider_windows
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.5"
    version: "2.0.7"
  petitparser:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -592,7 +599,7 @@ packages:
      name: win32
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.4.1"
    version: "2.5.2"
  xdg_directories:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -613,7 +620,7 @@ packages:
      name: yaml
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.0"
    version: "3.1.1"
  yaon:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
@ -623,4 +630,4 @@ packages:
    version: "1.0.0+1"
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.8.0"
  flutter: ">=2.8.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the you executed repo update when installing pods. You can try these

1. Delete pubspec.lock file
2. Delete podfile.lock from ios folder
3. Delete Pods folder from ios
4. Delete .symlinks folder from ios
5. Do flutter clean
6. Clear derived data
7. If you are using android studio go to file -> invalidate cache and restart.
8. Then from terminal navigate to ios folder run pod install
9. Open xcworkspace file from xcode and try building it once. All subsequent builds should work from your ide if it works from xcode once

Comment: I do it, but same problem like from VSC, at XCode I see at the end:
`/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.3/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:2413:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<TimeOfDay?> showTimePicker({
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to package /Users/qqq/data/github/qqqq/qqqqq.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`